# Remove duplicate phrases in a row within Excel cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have this string of data:

Adam~d032Bowker~d0091470~d032Timberlake~d032Dr~d032~d032~d032~d032~d009Clinton~d009NC~d00928328

If you notice towards the end, "~d032" is repeated 4 times. I want some sort of formula or macro to remove the last 3 "~d032" instances, but not touch the first instance or other instances throughout the cell such as the "Adam~d032" at the beginning.

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks,
Adam

Comment: Is the string you always want to remove the same length, is there always the same number, is there always the same number found beforehand, etc.  Is there an alpha/numeric pattern these repeating strings will follow.  The substitute method below does exactly what you ask for but is very text specific to what you have given as a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=SUBSTITUTE("Adam~d032Bowker~d0091470~d032Timberlake~d032Dr~d032~d032~d032~d032~d009Clinton~d009NC~d00928328","~d032~d032~d032~d032","~d032")
```